# can't repeat text in editText using a button

Tags: java, android

I have a simple activity in android with a button and an editText widget.
I have referenced the resource for the button, created an instance variable for the button, and invoked the listener method on it.

When I run the application, the button prints to the edit text widget, but only once.
I cannot continue to type "0000000", which is the ideal output that I want, rather than being stuck on "0".

The code I have used is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btn1;
EditText text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);

    // set an onclick listener to listen for when the buttons are clicked
    toe.setOnClickListener(this);

    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSimple);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    text.setText(btn1.getText().toString());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Is there a method or a work around that I could implement in order to print more digits to the edit text view?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Change `text.setText(btn1.getText().toString());` to `text.setText(text.getText.toString()+btn1.getText().toString());`

Comment: Try that if you want to repeat the text in edittext..

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lal, unfortunately that line has crashed it :(

Comment: what is the error you are getting in Logcat???

Comment: Do one thing..Before setting text `String t=text.getText().toString();` and then `text.setText(t+btn1.getText().toString());`

Comment: the error is 05-14 19:24:27.836: W/dalvikvm(3826): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e402a0)

Comment: The second line also leads to the thread error

Comment: Post your logcat please...

Comment: @Lal it is likely a NPE on text.getText.toString(). If the TextView doesn't have a set text it will be null. In onCreate, after you declare text, do text.setText(""); and it should fix the problem (if my assumption is correct).

Comment: Thank you to Lal and zgc! you've fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
text.setText(btn1.getText().toString());
```

with

```
String t=text.getText().toString();
text.setText(t+btn1.getText().toString())
```

Comment: While it doesn't matter in this small example this is really not the correct solution to a problem where there is an explicit API that 1) doesn't involve the creation of a temp variable, 2) is less verbose, 3) makes it obvious what is being done just by looking at the method name

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel here.  You don't even have to use direct Strings.

Your onClick could simply be:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    text.append(btn.getText());
}
```

Also, I don't know what "toe" is in

```
toe.setOnClickListener(this);
```

but you should be setting the clicklistener on btn1